# MySQL m:n relation query through linking table returns null in production 8.0.13 but works locally 5.7.30

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

using following MySQL schema for relations:

table *user* with PK *user_id*
table *blog* with PK *blog_id* and FK *user_id*
table *tag* with PK *tag_id*
and linking table *blog_tag* with PK's and FK's as *blog_id* and *tag_id* (both ON DELETE CASCADE)

1) When developing locally on Ubuntu 18.04.1 with Node (12.16.2), Express (4.17.1) and mysql (2.18.2) the below query works no problem using mysql server 5.7.30 (client 14.14 if it matters):

```
"SELECT b.*
      , JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', t.tag_id, 'name', t.name, 'color', t.color)) AS tags 
   FROM blog b 
   JOIN blog_tag bt 
     ON bt.blog_id = b.blog_id 
   JOIN tag t 
     ON bt.tag_id = t.tag_id 
  WHERE b.blog_id = ?", [req.params.blog_id]
```

This is for the show page where it returns single blog together with array of tags as json objects. Works fine locally.

When running against production database (Clever Cloud MySQL add-on mysql server 8.0.13), the show query above returns result with every column **null**. Why??

2) When using exact query above but changing to LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN it works fine in production. Why is JOIN working in MySQL 5 but not MySQL 8 and what effect would LEFT JOIN have compared to JOIN to not break it?

Hope it's clear enough and thanks for help.

Comment: without data it is hard to tell, LEFT JOIN takes all rows from the left table and joins all rows from right that fit, if you get all NULL is that the join find no match

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think mysql version differences play any role, join is a join. However, you really should keep your dev and prod environments closer aligned because there are significant differences between mysql 5.7 and 8.0.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] PS Show what goes between layers (express, node, client, server, CC, javascript) is OK & debug within one layer at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is an aggregation query because `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` is an aggregation function.

You have no `GROUP BY`.  Hence, all values in the `SELECT` should be arguments to aggregation functions.  If there were a `GROUP BY`, the unaggregated columns would need to be compatible with the `GROUP BY` keys.

But, you have `SELECT b.*` -- so lots of columns are clearly not aggregated. This is a syntax error in SQL

The problem is that you have a malformed query that used to work with the default settings in MySQL because it allowed such malformed queries.  Happily, that has been fixed in MySQL 8+, so the query does not work.